# Cant move the launcher to bottom in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'm trying to change my launcher from being on the left to the bottom. I've tried everything but it just wont.

[image]

[image]

I even tried the command line method many times.

Any help to get?

Comment: This is because it's not Unity any more, Ubuntu 17.10 came with GNOME.